# Jupyter Notebook - ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Tags: pip, lxml

After doing

```
pip install lxml
```

and importing the module still can't use it. Any suggestion ?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: It's actually a virtual machine running remotely connected to a python interpreter, therefore it's harder to debug. I have finally chosen to use another library for parsing. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This problem sometimes occurs due to having installed packages for python in a different envirnment.
In your PC command line type

```
where python
```

Then type the same in Jupyter Notebook terminal. The output should match, if it doesn't then here is your issue.
for macOS or linux do the same only change the command to

```
Which python
```

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this help you out?